# PushModalAsync after dismissviewcontroller crash app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Auth to connect via Google. When the authentication is done and ok I do :

```
UIViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

Then, I click on a button and I'm trying to make a pushmodalasync :

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(navigationPage)
```

When I do it, my application crash with this exception :

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'PlatformRenderer'. at
>   Foundation.NSObject.get_SuperHandle () [0x0004a] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:456
>   at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x0002a] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:2983
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.EndEditing () [0x00051] in
>   <7402bf39df944a9ebf61606e5f9c45a4>:0 at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page modal, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in
>   <7402bf39df944a9ebf61606e5f9c45a4>:0 at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationProxy.OnPushModal
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page modal, System.Boolean animated) [0x00022] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:212 at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Application+NavigationImpl.<>n__1 (Xamarin.Forms.Page
>   modal, System.Boolean animated) <0x103c59040 + 0x0004b> in
>   <209f66ed8fe04cb6a815feb8c3b62471#9e100c547031591382a60437c9f2f5db>:0
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Application+NavigationImpl+d__3.MoveNext
>   () [0x00065]

If I don't do the

```
UIViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

my app doesn't crash.

Here is the code of the full page for the connection with google in iOS :

```
public class GoogleLoginPageIos : IGoogleLoginPage
  {
    public static GoogleAuthenticator m_auth;
    private static UIViewController viewController;

    public void OnAuthenticationCompleted()
    {
      viewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationCanceled()
    {
      viewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationFailed()
    {
      viewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }

    public void StartAuthentication(Action onStartLogin, Action<Account> onSuccessfullLogin)
    {
      m_auth = new GoogleAuthenticator(onStartLogin, onSuccessfullLogin, this);

      var authenticator = m_auth.OAuth2Authenticator;
      var mainViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
      viewController = authenticator.GetUI();

      mainViewController.PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
    }
  }
```

I'm using a tabbedpage.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: What VC instance is `UIViewController`? Is it your Forms' app (seems like it)....

Comment: It's ```authenticator.GetUI();``` instance

Comment: Add the full exception/stacetrace to your question

Comment: Ok, it's done :-)

Comment: Can you share all related codes in that page? I'm confused about if you are using a Xamarin.forms app or a Xamarin.iOS app? Why is UIViewController appears in a Xamarin.forms app?

Comment: I'm using xamarin.forms but this is the code for ios only. I've added my code.

Comment: Can you try add a delay before you make a pushmodalasync? For example,`await Task.Delay(100);` and then `await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(navigationPage)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain myself. The pushmodalasync is done when I click on a button, no matter how long I wait, the application crash

Comment: Can you provide a demo with simplest code to reproduce this problem? I can't reproduce it on my side.

Comment: I think I found someone who is having the same problem... What he also mentionned is that he is using a tabbedpage like me : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2208